# Snowflake SQL Procedure and Cursor

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on a SQL procedure to read data from cursor and insert into table. How do i reference the cursor values in insert statement.

Below is what i have tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_FACT_SALES()
returns varchar(100)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '
declare
    
    INVOICE_NUMBER varchar(15);
    CUSTOMER    VARCHAR(20);
    AMOUNT  NUMBER(17,2);
    c1 cursor for select INVOICE_NUMBER,CUSTOMER,AMOUNT from db.schema.v_fact_sales limit 3;
begin
    open c1;
    
    fetch c1 into INVOICE_NUMBER,CUSTOMER,AMOUNT ;
    
    
    insert into db.schema.fact_sales(INVOICE_NUMBER,CUSTOMER,AMOUNT)
    values(c1.INVOICE_NUMBER,c1.CUSTOMER,c1.AMOUNT)
end ;
';
```

I am getting below error:

```
Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 14 at position 1 : SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 11 invalid identifier 'C1.INVOICE_NUMBER'
```

Do i have to FOR loop to reference cursor values or is there so way to bulk collect(similar to Oracle)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this resolved? Even i'm facing same issue with FOR LOOP as well. Able to handle this using intermediate variables but cant use cursor values directly inside INSERT VALUES clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a FOR loop to iterate through the cursor: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/for.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_FACT_SALES()
returns varchar(100)
LANGUAGE SQL

EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$ 
begin
declare
    
    INVOICE_NUMBER varchar(15);
    CUSTOMER    VARCHAR(20);
    AMOUNT  NUMBER(17,2);
    SQL1 STRING;
    c1 cursor for (select INVOICE_NUMBER,CUSTOMER,AMOUNT from 
    db.schema.v_fact_sales limit 3);
    begin
    SQL1:='';
    for record in c1 do
    open c1;
    sql1:=concat('insert into 
    db.schema.fact_sales(INVOICE_NUMBER,CUSTOMER,AMOUNT)
    values(',record.INVOICE_NUMBER,record.CUSTOMER,record.AMOUNT));
    return :sql1;
    ---execute immediate :sql1;
    end for;
    end ;
    $$;
```

Try running this and see the output statement. If it works, try with the `execute immediate :sql1;` by commenting the `return :sql1;` line.